# Start Countdown on Click and Resume - Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, preventdefault, pause

Thanks again for everyone and your help. So far I have been able to have a 2 minute timer in JS.

- I have made a functioning Pause Button, however:

1. I want the 2 minute timer to start when I click my start button [with the event listener]. It is currently starting automatically.
2. I want my start button to resume the timer point that I left off on after pressing the pause button.

Here is my code so far. I think I need to use a preventDefault or setTimeout event but I am not quite sure. All of your helpful answers are really helping me becoming comfortable building my first project, thank you all again :)

```
        let paused = false
        const startingMinutes = 2
        let time = startingMinutes * 60
        let timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)
    
        function countDown() {
    
          let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
          let seconds = time % 60
          time--
          console.log(minutes, 'minutes:', seconds, 'seconds')
          if (time <= 0) {
            console.log('Time is up!')
            clearInterval(timerId)
    }
    countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + seconds + ' seconds '
        }
    
    
        startBtn.addEventListener('click', countDown)
    
        function pauseGame() {
            if (paused === true || !paused === true) {
            startBtn.removeEventListener('click', countDown)
            clearInterval(timerId)
            }
        }
    
       pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        pauseGame()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes :

1. the timer is not running when you first run the code, so it should be equal to true.

   ```
   let paused = true
   ```
2. let's put your initial setInterval inside the eventListener, so it starts the countdown after clicking the start button:

   ```
   let timerId ; // just initialize the timerId variable, without a value, so you can access it inside your functions

    startBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      paused=false
      timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)

      })
   ```
3. also edit the pauseGame function, no need to remove the eventListener from startButton:

   ```
       function pauseGame() {
           paused=true
           clearInterval(timerId)
         }
   ```
4. one fix! if we click on the start button continuously, new intervals are gonna be executed by the browser, making the remaining seconds finish sooner than needed, we could prevent this by checking if the timer is already running

   ```
     startBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
         if (paused===false) {return;}
         paused = false
         timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)
      })
   ```